# Running aws-cdk in docker container breaks lambda bundling. How can I use nodejs lambda bundling anyway?

Tags: docker, aws-cdk

I'm running `cdk deploy` inside a docker container within a Jenkins pipeline. If I want to use aws-lambda-nodejs as bundling it tries to start a docker container inside the running container and fails since docker executable is not present. Is there any option to use aws-lambda-nodejs when running cdk inside a container?

Comment: I found a solution:

so I investigated that a little. Well its not directly attached to cdk but nevermind...

In my Dockerfile I added `docker` (using image `node:12.16.1-alpine`) to be added and mounted the volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock in the docker-compose file..Therefore the container (and cdk) is able to spwan a docker process which runs as container in the host (jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

Asker resolved the issue by adding docker as a dependency to the Dockerfile on the runner.

> I found a solution: so I investigated that a little. Well its not directly attached to cdk but nevermind... In my Dockerfile I added docker (using image node:12.16.1-alpine) to be added and mounted the volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock in the docker-compose file..Therefore the container (and cdk) is able to spawn a docker process which runs as container in the host (jenkins)